# How can I design a UI state class in ViewModel when I use Android Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I hope to design UI state class inside ViewModel to launch UI  recomposition when a state changed.

I have read some sample projects such as  https://github.com/android/compose-samples and https://github.com/android/architecture-samples

I find that these sample projects design a UI state class  with the Code A way, I don't understand the benefits of Code A.

You know I have to create many private variables such as  `private val selectedCategory` and  `private val categories` in Code A, and write  `combine( categories, selectedCategory ) { categories, selectedCategory ->...}` one by one.
If the  structure of `data class HomeViewState(...)`  changed, I have to change other codes everywhere.

I don't know why people doesn't use Code B, I think it's sample, and it adapt to change of `data class HomeViewState(...)`, What are the disadvantages of this approach in Code B?

**Code A**

```
class HomeViewModel(
) : ViewModel() {

    private val selectedCategory = MutableStateFlow(HomeCategory.Discover)
    private val categories = MutableStateFlow(HomeCategory.values().asList())

    private val _state = MutableStateFlow(HomeViewState())
    val state: StateFlow<HomeViewState>
        get() = _state

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            combine(
                categories,
                selectedCategory

            ) { categories, selectedCategory ->
                HomeViewState(
                    homeCategories = categories,
                    selectedHomeCategory = selectedCategory
                )
            }.catch { throwable ->
                // TODO: emit a UI error here. For now we'll just rethrow
                throw throwable
            }.collect {
                _state.value = it
            }
        }
    }

    fun onHomeCategorySelected(category: HomeCategory) {
        selectedCategory.value = category
    }
}

enum class HomeCategory {
    Library, Discover
}

data class HomeViewState(
    val selectedHomeCategory: HomeCategory = HomeCategory.Discover,
    val homeCategories: List<HomeCategory> = emptyList()
)
```

**Code B**

```
class HomeViewModel(
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _state = MutableStateFlow(HomeViewState())
    val state: StateFlow<HomeViewState>
        get() = _state

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _state.update { it.copy(
                selectedHomeCategory= HomeCategory.Discover,
                homeCategories = HomeCategory.values().toList()
            ) }
        }
    }

    fun onHomeCategorySelected(category: HomeCategory) {
        _state.update { it.copy(selectedHomeCategory = category) }      
    }
}

enum class HomeCategory {
    Library, Discover
}

data class HomeViewState(
    val selectedHomeCategory: HomeCategory = HomeCategory.Discover,
    val homeCategories: List<HomeCategory> = emptyList()
)
```

Comment: I agree with you. Code B is a cleaner way to handle it. Your `init` block could also be removed, and instead you could directly set the initial value to have those property values. So it would be even more concise.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I'd choose code B too. I can think of a couple of scenarios I'd choose option A; either I need to access the `selectedCategory`  and `categories` variables in other functions inside the ViewModel, or a situation like [this](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/JetNews/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetnews/ui/interests/InterestsViewModel.kt) for instance where the initialization is not just passing a value but calling/observing repo functions (cleaner code, easier debugging)

Comment: Can you please provide an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/q/76552050/3598052, one downside I can think of emitting larger data class is entire screen will recompose.