# Why do I get the error "Too many arguments for fun <T1, T2, R> Flow<T1>.combine(flow: Flow<T2>, transform: suspend (a: T1, b: T2) -> R): Flow<R>"

Tags: android, kotlin

The Code A displays the following error:

*Too many arguments for public fun <T1, T2, R> Flow.combine(flow: Flow, transform: suspend (a: T1, b: T2) -> R): Flow defined in kotlinx*

It seems that `combine(...)` accepts max 5 parameters, but I don't know why `.combine(  _playingMInfo,_playState   )`  cause error, why?

Do I must to use Code B?

**Code A**

```
 val homeUIState: StateFlow<HomeUIState> =  combine(
        _loadingDataResult, _recordingState, _eSortBy, _elapsedTime, _expandedListMInfoID
    ) {
        loadingDataResult, recordingState, eSortBy, elapsedTime, expandedListMInfoID  ->

        val basedHomeUIState = HomeUIState(  )
       ...
        
    }.combine(
        _playingMInfo,_playState
    ) {
        homeUIState, playingMInfo, playState ->

        homeUIState.copy(playingMInfo = playingMInfo, playState = playState)
    }
        .stateIn(
            viewModelScope,
            SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(),
            HomeUIState()
        )
```

**Code B**

```
val homeUIState: StateFlow<HomeUIState> =  combine(
        _loadingDataResult, _recordingState, _eSortBy, _elapsedTime, _expandedListMInfoID
    ) {
        loadingDataResult, recordingState, eSortBy, elapsedTime, expandedListMInfoID  ->

        val basedHomeUIState = HomeUIState(  )
       ...
        
    }.combine(
        _playingMInfo
    ) {
        homeUIState, playingMInfo ->

        homeUIState.copy(playingMInfo = playingMInfo)
    }
   .combine(
        __playState
    ) {
        homeUIState, playState ->

        homeUIState.copy(playState = playState)
    }
        .stateIn(
            viewModelScope,
            SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(),
            HomeUIState()
        )
```

Comment: They simply don’t have an overload that is an extension function and also allows more than one other flow than the receiver. Probably because that could be considered an awkward construction since when you’re combing multiple flows, none of them are more important than the others.

Comment: You confuse `combine()` extension and `combine()` top level function. Extension supports only two flows, function supports 2-5 flows (and even more).

Comment: Thanks! It seems that combine(...) accepts max 5 parameters,

Comment: There's an overload that accepts a vararg, so it's unlimited, but if you use that one, it will use a common type for all of them and pass them to the lambda as a list.

Comment: Thanks!   Would you please see the relation  question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76413039/how-can-i-design-a-ui-state-class-in-viewmodel-when-i-use-android-jetpack-compos ?

With Code A,  it's easy reach  to combine 10 Flows for UI state.

Comment: And more, could you give me a sample to use a common type for all of them and pass them to the lambda as a list ?