# Optimal way to collect many flows which represents Ui state in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, kotlin-flow

I'm trying migrate to Jetpack Compose in my Android app. My screen contains lots of flags and each item should be visible (and start receiving data) only if corresponding flag is set to true. The problem is that I'm updating item's data using flows and I'm wary that too many flows may lead to freezings on main thread and laggy ui.

For example my ui state looks like this (it's only example, my real code is more complicated, but problem is same):

```
data class UiState(
    val showFavoriteBlock: Boolean,
    val showRecentlyVisitedBlock: Boolean,
    val showMostPopularBlock: Boolean,
    val showSubscriptionBlock: Boolean,
    val showFriendsBlock: Boolean,
    val showRelatedBlock: Boolean,
    val showLatestVisitedBlock: Boolean,
    // There is 10+ same flags
    
    // And here I have content for each block which starts loading after we receive flag
    val favorites: Flow<List<...>>,
    // 10+ flows for each block
)
```

Right now I have next code for root composable function

```
@Composable
fun ExampleScreen(uiState: UiState){
    // We don't show screen untill all flags will be received,
    // flags itself are simple Booleans. But content for them is flow

    LazyColumn {
        // reading flag's value doesn't force recomposition
        // because it's not State<Boolean> and can't be changed
        if(uiState.showFavoriteBlock){
            item{
                // we sending flow, so updates in flow right now
                // cannot force recomposition of screen
                FavoritesBlock(uiState.favorites)
            }
        }
        // 10+ items for each block
        ...
    }
}
```

And here is my RecentlyVisitedBlock composable:

```
@Composable
fun RecentlyVisitedBlock(recentlyVisitedFlow: Flow<List<RecentlyVisitedData>>) {
    // recentlyVisited is State<RecentlyVisitedData>
    val recentlyVisited by recentlyVisitedFlow.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    Row {
        // Here I'm reading state and this causes recomposition for all RecentlyVisitedBlock
        // So recomposition happens only when we receive new data from flow
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm collecting more than 10 flows in composable functions. And... is it ok?
All examples in codelabs, jetpack compose examples and tutorials contains around 3-4 flows. But real applications can have around 20-30 (or even more) flows which can frequently emit data. It's okay to work with flows in background, but here I collecting all of them on ui.

So my questions are:

- Is it okay to have 10+ (or even 20-30) flows and collect them independently in composable functions? May it lead to performance problems? Because main thread should handle all of them
- I can merge all flows in one inside UiState and then use `filterIsInstance` to filter and sent to each composable only its data. In this case I still have 10+ calls of `collectAsState` function but at least there is only one flow instead of 10+. Is it okay to modify flows on ui? Merge them, map, filter.
- I also can change my UiState and add State fields. But in this case I'll have 10+ flows and 10+ similar State values. Looks like bad pattern
- What if I change my Screen to `ExampleScreen(uiState: Flow<UiState>)`. In this case I have only 1 flow with single call of `collectAsStateWithLifecycle`, but it will cause recomposition of root on each change. Also I can use derivedStateOf and skip recompositions of some children. What is better: have multiple flows which collects and reading state in place independently or have 1 flow, which causes recomposition of root on each update?

---

> In the 1st case, the UiState will be more readable.  In the 2nd case,
> you will need one state for every value (Ex : Email, password,
> loading, error etc..). The problem is that there will be a lot of
> state in your ViewModel and your Composables.
>
> To summarize, the first option offers improved readability but leads
> to a higher number of recompositions. On the other hand, the second
> option is better suited for handling recompositions.

As mentioned in the comment by @Mehdi.ncb, I am trying to find an official recommendation by Google and Performance analysis to decide on which one to implement 1) Large Screen level UiState(https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state-hoisting#screen-ui-state) that emits Data class with 50+ fields that recomposes entire screen Or 2) Individual flowable fields with less recompose counts.

Comment: I currently have the same issue. There are actually two cases. In the 1st case, the UiState will be more readable. In the 2nd case, you will need one state for every value (Ex : Email, password, loading, error etc..). The problem is that there will be a lot of state in your ViewModel and your Composables.

To summarize, the first option offers improved readability but leads to a higher number of recompositions. On the other hand, the second option is better suited for handling recompositions. After testing both approaches, I personally prefer the second option.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but to provide the context of two different solution and how it impacts the recomposition. So looking for a preferred or recommended solution in terms of performance and code architecture.

**Solution 1: Large UiState(may contain 50+ fields) that recompose entire screen.**

```
data class UiState(
    val sellerCount: Int,
    val buyerCount: Int
)

private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow<UiState>(
        UiState(
            sellerCount = 0,
            buyerCount = 0
        )
 )
 val uiState: StateFlow<UiState> = _uiState

setContent {
            RecomposeTestTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    val screenUiState = uiState.collectAsState().value

                    Column {
                        SellerUiComponent(
                            sellerCount = screenUiState.sellerCount,
                            onClickSellerIncrement = {
                                _uiState.update {
                                    it.copy(
                                        sellerCount = it.sellerCount + 1
                                    )
                                }
                            }
                        )
                        BuyerUiComponent(
                            buyerCount = screenUiState.buyerCount,
                            onClickBuyerIncrement = {
                                _uiState.update {
                                    it.copy(
                                        buyerCount = it.buyerCount + 1
                                    )
                                }
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
@Composable
fun SellerUiComponent(sellerCount: Int, onClickSellerIncrement: () -> Unit) {
    Button(
        onClick = onClickSellerIncrement,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(100.dp)
            .padding(16.dp)
    ) {
        Text(text = "Increase Seller")
    }

    Text(
        text = "Seller Count  $sellerCount",
        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
    )
}

@Composable
fun BuyerUiComponent(buyerCount: Int, onClickBuyerIncrement: () -> Unit) {
    Button(
        onClick = onClickBuyerIncrement,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(100.dp)
            .padding(16.dp)
    ) {
        Text(text = "Increase Buyer")
    }

    Text(
        text = "Buyer Count  $buyerCount",
        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
    )
}
```

Solution 1 causes [entire screen to be recomposed](https://gist.github.com/chitrang200889/3ff7702842b199958cb118657df0885b?permalink_comment_id=4843076#gistcomment-4843076).

**Solution 2: Smaller MutableStates that recompose only UI Component.**

```
data class SellerData(val count: Int)
    
data class BuyerData(val count: Int)

@Stable
class UiState {
    val sellerData = mutableStateOf<SellerData>(SellerData(0))
    val buyerData = mutableStateOf<BuyerData>(BuyerData(0))
}

private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow<UiState>(UiState())
val uiState: StateFlow<UiState> = _uiState

        setContent {
            RecomposeTestTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    val screenUiState = uiState.collectAsState().value

                    Column {
                        SellerUiComponent(screenUiState.sellerData)
                        BuyerUiComponent(screenUiState.buyerData)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    

@Composable
fun SellerUiComponent(sellerData: MutableState<SellerData>) {
    Button(
        onClick = { sellerData.value = sellerData.value.copy(sellerData.value.count + 1) },
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(100.dp)
            .padding(16.dp)
    ) {
        Text(text = "Increase Seller")
    }

    Text(
        text = "Seller Count  ${sellerData.value.count}",
        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
    )
}

@Composable
fun BuyerUiComponent(buyerData: MutableState<BuyerData>) {
    Button(
        onClick = { buyerData.value = buyerData.value.copy(buyerData.value.count + 1) },
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(100.dp)
            .padding(16.dp)
    ) {
        Text(text = "Increase Buyer")
    }

    Text(
        text = "Buyer Count  ${buyerData.value.count}",
        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
    )
}
```

Solution 2 [only recompose the UiComponent and not entire screen](https://gist.github.com/chitrang200889/28600e4ef8a023a66bec121acbbebe3a?permalink_comment_id=4843075#gistcomment-4843075).

Answer (score 0):

Avoid incorporating `Flow` into your `UiState`. The UiState should only encompass basic, immutable data and models to ensure that the data isn’t updated unless a new UiState is generated. Collecting a flow from your UiState can lead to an inconsistent state in your app, as it loses the single source of truth. Regardless of how frequently your UiState needs to be updated, your UI must always access the most recent, consistent UI state from a single source, which can be a `StateFlow` in your ViewModel. I recommend using `ViewModel` in your project because it makes it easier to handle this issue especially when you're using `Jetpack Compose`.

For instance, replace `val favorites: Flow<List<...>>` with `val favorites: List<...>` and place your UiState in a StateFlow in your ViewModel as shown below:

```
data class UiState(
    val showFavoriteBlock: Boolean = false,
    val showRecentlyVisitedBlock: Boolean = false,
    val showMostPopularBlock: Boolean = false,
    val showSubscriptionBlock: Boolean = false,
    val showFriendsBlock: Boolean = false,
    val showRelatedBlock: Boolean = false,
    val showLatestVisitedBlock: Boolean = false,

    val favorites: List<Favorites> = emptyList(),
    val news: List<News> = emptyList(),
)

class YourViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow<UiState>(UiState())
    val uiState: StateFlow<UiState> = _uiState
    ...
}
```

You can then update your uiState in your ViewModel wherever you need. You can collect different flows in your ViewModel and update your UiState in them, like so:

```
favortiteFlow.collect{ it ->
    uiState.update {
        it.copy(
            showFavoriteBlock = true,
            favorites = it
        )
    }
}

newsFlow.collect{ it ->
    uiState.update {
        it.copy(
            news = it
        )
    }
}
```

The `it.copy` method is used because the UiState is immutable, and we want to copy the previous state and only modify the data that we need to change.

then you can collect your UiState like this in your compose screen:

```
val uiState = yourViewModel.uiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle().value
```

and use the updated State where you want.
Also to improve the recomposition issue you can use `@Stable` and `@Immutable` annotations based on your use.

Comment: My concern is, every time uiState.update { it.copy() } there is .copy and emit of new UiState then val uiState = yourViewModel.uiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle().value new state is collected at screen level (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state-hoisting#screen-ui-state), this way entire screen will be recomposed. And if screen is very long with many UI components then it does not make sense to recompose entire screen each time.

Comment: So, to be clear with @Squti approach

Do you recommend to trigger recomposition of full screen each time any part of uiState changes? Cause reading State triggers recomposition. And yes, some nodes may be skipped, but not all and it anyway kinda expensive operation because system will spend some time to verify if anything changed. In your example changes in favorite block will trigger recomposition of news (and actually all other) blocks. Is it fair trade off?

Comment: If you want to optimize recomposition the solution is not putting flow or any other mutable data in your UiState. Trigger the UiState to update data in your use case is less expensive than you think. There are more complex scenarios that Compose can handle and If you need optimization there are best practices that you can follow for specific scenarios on YouTube and other websites. Putting flow in the UiState has a lot more cost than the optimization you gain because it is an Anti Pattern and it makes your implementation very complex, hard to debug, and hard to change in the future. @Chitrang

Comment: If you separate your composable views and just pass the data that view needs instead of the entire UiState the sub-views won't update. @someone1231

Comment: "Putting flow in the UiState has a lot more cost than the optimization you gain because it is an Anti Pattern and it makes your implementation very complex, hard to debug, and hard to change in the future." -> Not sure if it is completely true and coming from any official reference from google because google is also suggesting uses of @stable annotation and holding mutableStates in it https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/Jetsnack/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetsnack/ui/home/search/Search.kt#L153 as mentioned in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77275808/3598052.

Comment: If you separate your composable views and just pass the data that view needs instead of the entire UiState the sub-views won't update.  -> Please check this github gist https://gist.github.com/chitrang200889/3ff7702842b199958cb118657df0885b where I am just passing the necessary data in the UiComponent level composable event that entire screen is being recompose as you can seen in layout inspector count in the video.

Comment: The best practice is to put immutable data in UiState it does not matter if it is Flow, List, or primitive data. Your Flow is mutable so you should not put it in the UiState.[Check this Link.](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/ui-layer#state-immutability)
to prevent updating the subviews you can use drivedstateof , if..else statements or any other mechanism to prevent your subview update.

Comment: In your link they say that uiState should be immutable cause it prevents situation with multiple sources of truth. Here is the quote

"This frees up the UI to focus on a single role: to read the state and update its UI elements accordingly. As a result, you should never modify the UI state in the UI directly unless the UI itself is the sole source of its data"

So,in case my uiState consists of Flows(as in my original question),which are val (immutable) and you can't emit data in them (They are even more immutable), does it counts as immutable? UiState still has only one source of truth

Comment: I understand what are you talking about. With xml-based ui my uiState doesn't contain any reactive structures like flows, defferable or observable. They are useless cause you can precompute them and simply pass to views. But there is databinding (i hope it still alive), for example, which accepts reactive structures. Lots of examples for composable apps provided by google contain flow in uiState. So that question can't be answered with "don't use mutable variables" because for xml-based views it was unnecessary

Comment: I still can have uiState with flow and single source of truth.And it will work well if each flow represents immutable uiState(without flows in it) for independent element on ui. Flow will be passed to separated composable and will trigger recomposition of only one element. It has single source of truth and access to most recent state (if i use stateFlow for example). I can't understand right now why it's antipattern (even if google recommend to use flows in uiState). My initial question was mainly about performance issues that may be caused by multiple flows collected on ui though. @Squti